# How to turn a string of numbers into a list

Tags: python, string, integer

How do I split a string containing mostly numbers into a list?  I tried `str.split()` but since each number is separated by a comma I can't turn the string into a list of integers.
for example:

```
a='text,2, 3, 4, 5, 6'
```

when I do `split` I get

```
b=['text,2,', '3,', '4,', '5,', '6']
```

Is there any way to isolate the integers into a list?

Answer (score 3):

Use `regex`:

```
>>> a = 'text,2, 3, 4, 5, 6' 
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', a)
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

---

Non-regex solution using `str.isdigit` and a List comprehension:

```
>>> [y for y in  (x.strip() for x in a.split(',')) if y.isdigit()]
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

---

If you want the string to be converted to integers then just call `int()` on the items in the list.

```
>>> import re
>>> [int(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'\d+', a)]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> [int(y) for y in  (x.strip() for x in a.split(',')) if y.isdigit()]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: you might have forgot to convert y to int(y).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't use Regex:

```
>>> a='text,2, 3, 4, 5, 6'
>>> # You could also do "[x for x in (y.strip() for y in a.split(',')) if x.isdigit()]"
>>> # I like this one though because it is shorter
>>> [x for x in map(str.strip, a.split(',')) if x.isdigit()]
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> [int(x) for x in map(str.strip, a.split(',')) if x.isdigit()]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```